# How do I get the argument values within Autofac's OnActivated handler?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

If I have the following classes:

```
public class A  {}
public class B { public B(A a) {…} }
```

And I register `OnActivated` for `B`:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>().AsSelf().OnActivated(e => …)
```

How do I get the instance that was passed as `a` without requiring class `B` to expose it?

Comment: I don't think you can and IMO there is no problem in exposing `A` as a public property on `B`. This will not break encapsulation, since consumers of `B` should depend on an `IB` abstraction (that doesn't contain `A`) instead of depending on `B` directly.

Comment: Does your code has registered also A?

Comment: @Steven The problem I see with exposing `A` as a property is that I wouldn't have needed to do that if I hadn't used a DI framework. Any changes to components required to make framework happy = issue in a framework. If it's not possible right now I'll take a look at whether I can make a pull request to Autofac to add that (or at least an inverse feature where I could get a requesting type when activating a dependency).

Comment: @hugo yes, both `A` and `B` are registered. in this simple example both are registered `AsSelf`, though in real app there would be interfaces.

Comment: if you register A with .InstancePerLifetimeScope(), you can write you activated like (e => e.Resolve<A>()) .  You will get the same instance as resolved inside B

Comment: @hugo that's fair, but not a generic solution -- what if it is an InstancePerDependendency?

Comment: This is the default behavior.  You will receive a new instance each time your want to resolve A.  So the trick of e.Resolve<A>() will give you another instance

Comment: btw "it is not possible in current version" is a totally valid answer and it does not have to be in comments -- I'll approve it if there are no other solutions.

Comment: But why do you require `A` when activating `B`. There might be something smelly going on there. Can you describe what you're actually trying to during activation?

Comment: I want to record that `b` used `a` so that later when `C` gets `b` I could give it the same `a` without letting `B` know about `C`. I actually already solved the underlying problem with a different design since posting this, but it doesn't invalidate my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. @Hugo already commented about doing the resolve inside the activator delegate, like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>().AsSelf().OnActivated(e =>
{
    e.Resolve<A>();
})
```

This of course means that `A` needs to be registered with a lifestyle longer than transient (`InstancePerDependendency`).

A second option is to make `A` a public property on `B`. A third option is to create a class that derives from `B` and contains a public property of `A`. This implementation can be part of the composition root, and means you don't have to change anything in your application (except your composition root). Here's an example:

```
// Inside your Composition root
private sealed class C : B {
    public readonly A A;
    public C(A a) : base(a) { this.A = a }
}

builder.RegisterType<C>().As<B>().OnActivated(e => 
    e.Instance.A ...)
```

Do note that it is impossible for Autofac or any other container to supply you with `A` in a type-safe manner, since the constructor signature is not something that can be captured in a generic type constraint. So the best that Autofac would be able to do is supply you with a `List<object>` with the injected types. Here's an example:

```
// Hypothetical feature
builder.RegisterType<C>().As<B>().OnActivated(e => {
    A a = e.Dependencies.OfType<A>().Single();
})
```

The question here is which dependencies that list should have. What should the list contain in case a type is decorated or intercepted. Should the list contain the list of dependencies of the decorator/interceptor? Or should it contain all dependencies for all applied decorators and the dependencies of the type itself, or just the dependencies of that type.

Comment: Thanks. I think it covers my question pretty well -- and on the framework side I now think the right solution would be to provide requesting service instance to the dependency `OnActivated` instead.